# c# sizeof decimal?

Tags: c#

Unclear on the sizeof for decimal types. Does the size in bytes vary by precision as in sql server? Is the precision variable for the c# type 'decimal'?

I don't want to turn on unsafe code to just call sizeof on a decimal type. How would you approach this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As others have said, `decimal` is always 16 bytes (128 bits). The precision of `decimal` is always 28/29 digits. It's a floating point type, unlike SQL's `DECIMAL` type. See [my article on it](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Decimal) for more details.

Comment: This is by far the best answer if you click the link and read the article. MSDN stops short of explaining how it is stored which is really required at the primary reference source.

Answer (score 24):

> The decimal keyword indicates a 128-bit data type.

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(loband).aspx)

Comment: Yes loband looks great. 
For my basic problem, it now doesn't look efficient to replace float with decimal, because that a change from 32 bits to 128 bits. I am dealing with high rate instrument data collection.

Comment: Another +1 for the loband... getting the answer right helped, too, of course ;-p

Comment: Heh, seems like everybody has broadband :( Beside bandwidth problem which you don't know of :p, the page looks a lot better :)

Comment: I agree. The loband version is much easier on the eyes.

Comment: Cracking. Shame the links within it don't keep the loband-ness. I still have an ambition to work out a better way to find MSDN links for Stack Overflow.

Comment: There is a link at the top right to "persist low bandwidth view"

Answer (score 5):

The size of a System.Decimal in the .NET Framework is fixed at 16 Bytes.

Answer (score 1):

128-bit precise decimal values with 28-29 significant digits,
128 bit =  16 byte