# Overflow exception when reading decimal values from SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, decimal

I'm wondering whether this is a bug or if I'm going something wrong.

I'm loading values with a `SqlDataReader` from a SQL Server 2008 database but under certain circumstances, it fails to convert the SQL values into .net values. (.NET 4.0)

I have traced it down to an test-case which demonstrates the actual problem:

Working example:

```
"select convert(decimal(38, 19), 260000 ) as test"
rs.GetValue(1);
--> returns 260000 (decimal)
```

Not working exmaple:

```
"select convert(decimal(36, 26), 260000 ) as test"

rs.GetValue(1);
--> throws
   System.OverflowException: Conversion overflows.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Decimal()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Value()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValueInternal(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)
```

I have examined the actual values that the SQL Server retured. They differ that the non-working one uses 4 integers to express the value, the working one only 3.

I did also check the source code with .net Reflector which unveiled that an exception is thrown if the value exists of more then 3 values, but I dont understand the mechanics behind them.

So, I'm wondering whether this is a genuine bug in the .net framework.

Comment: Precision for decimal values is only upto 28 .Please go thru the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745270/c-sharp-sizeof-decimal

Comment: But the working example even uses a higher precision.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not something you are doing wrong, apart from being overly precise perhaps. I don't think its a [new problem either](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2010/08/31/when-does-sql-server-decimal-not-convert-to-net-decimal.aspx).

You could argue it's a bug or just a gap in functionality. The .Net `Decimal` structure just can't represent the value that is stored in your SQL Server `decimal` so an `OverflowException` is thrown.

Either you need to manipulate the value to something compatible in the database before you retrieve it or, read the data out in a raw binary or string format and manipulate it on the .Net side.

Alternatively, you could write a new type that handles it.

It's probably simpler just to use a compatible `decimal` definition in the first place unless you really need that precision. If you do I'd be interested to know why.

Comment: The precision parameters were chosen by the SQL server itself. I was originally doing some basic calculations on the server between (10,2) and (10,4) fields. The server picked (36,26) as the return type. I changed all fields to (18,4) now, and its working so far.

Comment: @Jodrell - like your username.. I live about 15 minutes from Jodrell Bank. Love visiting that area. Also this issue is so annoying we have a (30,20) in SQL we need to store it like that and we cant save or read it back.. even though it fits in Decimal. `System.Data.DataException : Error parsing column 1 (FactorCO2e=4 - Int32)
  ----> System.OverflowException : Conversion overflows.`