# “Conversion overflow” error occurred when trying to read decimal column value from table using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have created a table in SQL Sever database which has a column of type `decimal(38,8)`. One of the row contains a decimal value:

```
78814954463922041217457180628.36000000
```

An error

> Conversion overflow

has appeared when trying to read that data from C# code. I was using Entity Framework to read the data from database.

Table: `TestDecimal`

[image]

Rows in the table are as below :

[image]

Here is the C# code:

```
string conn = @"Data Source=.\SQLSERVER2012;Initial Catalog=SampleDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";

try
{
    Database dataBase = new SqlDatabase(conn);

    var cmd = dataBase.GetSqlStringCommand("Select * from TestDecimal");

    using (DataSet dsTxnQry = dataBase.ExecuteDataSet(cmd))
    {
        if (dsTxnQry.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Table exists");
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

I get error at `dataBase.ExecuteDataSet(cmd)` line. Please let me know the solution to resolve this problem.

I have my observation below in comments section. please refer to that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overflow exception when reading decimal values from SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326269/overflow-exception-when-reading-decimal-values-from-sql-server)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response, but the suggested solution may not be suitable in our application. Our’s is huge application(developed in C# with WPF) where we bind the datasource to the grid to appear on the screen. As mentioned in the possible solution in the referred link, if I use to string datatype to read, this will affect my output as few functions(Sum, average, etc.,) to number base columns will not appear. Moreover I did not understand the other suggested solutions which says either manipulate or write a new type. How is it possible, could you please elaborate with sample code

Comment: So your row contains a value that is (like it or not) to big for the `decimal` type. So you can now decide to either cut down precision until it fits into the decimal or use a different type where the value is supported as is. Noone can give you an answer how to fit this number into a decimal - it's just not happening.